# How to fold dimension of a tensor into a scalar in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, fold, tensor

I have an *n×m×l* tensor in MATLAB which I want to turn into an *n×m* matrix by folding the last dimension (specifically adding each scalar). How can I perform a fold / reduce of the last dimension of each entry in this tensor efficiently? **More broadly, is there a nice way to apply an arbitrary function to an entire dimension of a tensor?**

If it helps for understanding, the concrete tensor I have is called `pixels` and the last dimension is `l=3`and represents the R, G, and B values of each pixel, which I want to add to obtain brightness. The following solution I have come up with is painfully slow:

```
cellfun( @(x) sum(x), num2cell( pixels, 3 ) )
```

Comment: Matlab doesn't easily lend itself to work that way. There is no _fold_ higher-order function. Instead, there are _vectorized_ functions that do the folding for specific binary operations: `sum` for folding `+`, `prod` for folding `*` etc. This is to gain speed: the folding is done internally (probably in Java). As another example, for the higher-order function _map_ found in other languages, there are `arrayfun` and `cellfun`, but as you've seen they are slow, as the mapping is done in Matlab, not internally in Java. Bottom line: in Matlab it's better to think in terms of vectorized functions

Comment: As Adriaan suggested, post the actual computation you need to perform, we might be able to help you vectorize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum(pixels,3)
```

[`sum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) allows summation over any dimension given to it, so just give it the third dimension. Trailing dimensions are cut off automatically, so your matrix will end up as size n-by-m.

Otherwise, with general functions: use a loop. Loops are no longer very slow, whilst cells definitely are:

```
out = zeros(size(pixels,1),size(pixels,2));
for ii = 1:size(pixels,3)
    out(:,:) = YourFunc(pixels(:,:,ii));
end
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to perform a different kind of fold? Or apply an arbitrary function to the entire dimension?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "fold", but there are several functions (`min,max,mean,sum,cumsum` etc) that have this dimensional argument, otherwise: use a loop. Loops are no longer very slow in MATLAB, and definitely going through cells is way slower.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more elegant way than using loops, and my function is actually a bit more complicated than just summing (I simplified it for the question). Thanks anyways for your answer. If interested, see here for the definition of a fold: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29

Comment: @anroesti In that case your example is too *minimal* in the [mcve] department. Ask about the thing you want, not an oversimplified situation to get a proper answer. Whether loops are "elegant" is a matter of taste, in my opinion it's more elegant than a convoluted `cellfun` way.

Comment: More elegant and faster too!

Comment: Note that you can also loop over the first two dimensions instead of over the 3rd dimension. It depends on the function you need to apply.

Comment: I disagree on wether it is elegant or not but if there is no other way to do it I'll accept your answer.